# Strange output from java 8 file/word counting program

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

I'm working on an assignment which uses Java streams with lambda syntax. The program is supposed to be designed (1) To count a set of files (2) To count the words within those files (3) Print and display the result. This is an example of the output:

```
Count 11 files:
word length: 1 ==> 80
word length: 2 ==> 321
word length: 3 ==> 643
.....
```

However, I'm getting this output instead:

```
primes.txt
word length: 1 ==> hw8.WordCount@5c647e05
constitution.txt
word length: 2 ==> hw8.WordCount@33909752
short.txt
word length: 3 ==> hw8.WordCount@55f96302
.....
Count: 11 files
```

The program I've written is in two classes - `FileCatch`, which counts the files and `WordCount`, which counts the words (In theory). If anyone has any programming tips to help, I would be appreciated.

The `FileCatch` class

```
public class FileCatch8 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        List<String> fileNames = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            DirectoryStream<Path> directoryStream = Files.newDirectoryStream
        (Paths.get("files"));
            int fileCounter = 0;
            for (Path path : directoryStream) {
                System.out.println(path.getFileName());
                fileCounter++;
                fileNames.add(path.getFileName().toString());
                WordCount WordCnt = new WordCount();
                System.out.println("word length: " +  fileCounter + " ==> " + WordCnt);
            }
    }catch(IOException ex){
    }
    System.out.println("Count: "+fileNames.size()+ " files");

  }
}
```

The `WordCount` class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.AbstractMap.SimpleEntry;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.TreeMap;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.counting;
import static java.util.stream.Collectors.groupingBy;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/**
 *
 * @author GeraldShields
 */
public class WordCount {

    /**
     *
     * @return 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Map<String, Long> WordCount()throws IOException {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get("constitution.txt"));
        Map<String, Long> wordMap = lines
                .parallel()
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .map(line -> line.split("\\W+"))
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line).stream())
                .filter(word -> !word.matches("\\d+") && word.trim().length() != 0)
                .map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word, 1))
                .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, counting()));
        new TreeMap(wordMap).forEach((k, v) -> 
                System.out.println(String.format("%s word length: 1 ==> %d", k, v)));
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm using it to numbers the files Ex: File 1, File 2, etc.

Comment: @Eran All because someone found an Array and they thought it had been done before?!

Comment: @Eran the int counter worked. Thank you. However, I no longer have the option to edit the question. I just have the hw8.WordCount@33909752 stuff after placing int fileCounter = 0; fileCounter++ in the for loop and plugging fileCounter in the println statement.

Comment: @Eran I found it. Thank you again.

Comment: @Eran It's all changed now with the new lines.

Comment: @Eran Okay. the new output is above.

Answer (score 0):

You are printing an instance of your `WordCount` class, which makes no sense. You also never call the `WordCount()` method.

You should create a single instance of `WordCount` and call the method that performs the word count for each file (I renamed some of the methods and variables to make the code more readable):

```
WordCount wordCnt = new WordCount();
for (Path path : directoryStream) {
    System.out.println(path.getFileName());
    fileCounter++;
    fileNames.add(path.getFileName().toString()); 
    System.out.println("word length: " +  fileCounter + " ==> " + wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString()));
}


public class WordCount {

    /**
     *
     * @return 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public Map<String, Long> count(String filename) throws IOException {
        Stream<String> lines = Files.lines(Paths.get(filename));
        Map<String, Long> wordMap = lines
                .parallel()
                .map(String::toLowerCase)
                .map(line -> line.split("\\W+"))
                .flatMap(line -> Arrays.asList(line).stream())
                .filter(word -> !word.matches("\\d+") && word.trim().length() != 0)
                .map(word -> new SimpleEntry<>(word, 1))
                .collect(groupingBy(SimpleEntry::getKey, counting()));
        new TreeMap(wordMap).forEach((k, v) -> 
                System.out.println(String.format("%s word length: 1 ==> %d", k, v)));
        return wordMap;
    }
}
```

Note the your `WordCount` class seems to count the appearances of each word in a file, not the total number of words in a file, so it doesn't seem to match the expected output you posted at the start of your question.

Comment: @Eren just to check: Did you suggest to create a WordCount method? I'd tried these suggestions, but the complier had a problem with System.out.println("word length: " +  fileCounter + " ==> " + wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString()));

Comment: @JavaNewbie No, I renamed your `WordCount` method to `count` and added a `String` argument to it.

Comment: @JavaNewbie You have to change your `WordCount` class in order for `wordCnt.count(path.getFileName().toString())` to pass compilation.

Comment: @Eren Okay, but now the program only returns one of the files in the directory (primes.txt Count: 1 files) , nixes the file count And it doesn't do the word count for the file.